# PHP Curl into R httr

Tags: r, httr

I have totally no experience in this area. What I am trying to do is to send a post request to access an API which would return a JSON file.

This is the curl process in PHP:

```
$url = 'https://app.responseiq.com/apis/reports';       
$fields = array('token' => $api_key,
'offset' =>$offset,
'limit' =>$limit,
'widget_id'=>$widget_id
);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
```

This is what I have so far

```
httr::POST (
  url = "https://app.responseiq.com/apis/reports",
  query = list (
    token = "ABCDEF",
    offset =10,
    limit   =100,
    widget_id = "TEST"
  ),
  httr::content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
  httr::accept("application/json, text/javascript, */*; d=0.2"),
  httr::verbose()
  
)
```

I am not getting my expected output, which should be data in JSON format.
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. If I got my concept totally wrong, it would be great if someone can direct me in the right direction to learn more about using the httr package.Thank you.

Comment: `httr` never returns naked json. It returns an http response object, which (if you got the API call right) will be stored as binary data inside the response object. If you store the result from `httr::POST(...)`, by doing `res <- httr::POST(...)`, then you should be able to get the json in text format via `httr::content(res, 'text')`

Comment: Guess I got the API call wrong. Returned ""{\"msg\":\"Token field is required\"}"".

Comment: When using `POST`, use `body=` rather than `query=` when specifying your post payload. Also try just `encode="form"` rather than `httr::content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`. It's unclear where the `httr::accept` part is coming from since that doesn't seem to be in the php code.